# Bit Twiddle to perform this conversion

Tags: bit-manipulation, bit

curious if anyone might have some insight in how I would do the following to a binary number:

convert

```
   01+0 -> 10+1 (+ as in regular expressions, one or more)
    01 -> 10  
    10 -> 01
```

so,

```
10101000010100011100
01010100101010100010
```

and to clarify that this isn't a simple inversion:

```
000000100000000000
000001010000000000
```

I was thinking regex, but I'm working with binary numbers and want to stay that way. The [bit twiddling hacks](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html) page hasn't given me any insight either. This clearly has some essence of cellular automata. So, anyone have a few bit operations that can take care of this? (no code is necessary, I know how to do that).

Comment: I am having a hard time following what the first "01+0" -> "10+1" is suppose to mean. Your example conversion indicates that you don't want a simple one's compliment, but could you be more clear on the conversion you do want?

Comment: The example needs either correcting or clarifying. Currently the only 'sense' I can see in it is that if a 0 is next to a 1 in the source it becomes a 1 in the target. Otherwise the 0 stays a 0, and all 1s become 0

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let's say x is your variable.  Then you'd have:

```
unsigned myBitOperation(unsigned x)
{
    return ((x<<1) | (x>>1)) & (~x);
}
```

Comment: thanks//perfect! for some reason I forgot about shifting when I was thinking about a solution. *embarassed* that'll never happen again!!

Answer (score -2):

Twidle in C/C++ is ~

Comment: If you look carefully, this his example isn't strictly a one's compliment.

Comment: he did not specify base 10 for those 2 digits and his subject was bit twiddling. Hence I assume it is base to. Also I assume if I give him the basic tool he can figure out how to apply it in a more complex way.

Comment: Yes even, but you are assuming that there are 32 bits in his first set of examples. I only see 2 in most and only 1 in another. I kindly disagree I think it is a one's compliment problem.

Comment: Except that the poster edited his question and added "...and to clarify that this isn't a simple inversion".